# Error: package 'parser' not found

Tags: ros, urdf, beginner-tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm trying to follow http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Parse%20a%20urdf%20file after having completed all of the introductory tutorials.

I think I may not be following some of the shorthand in this tutorial correctly.  I believe I have created the parser.cpp file and the URDF file in the correct locations within `~/catkin_ws/src/testbot_description/`.

At the  end of the tutorial it says "build your package and run it".  I navigate to `~/catkin_ws/src/` and run `catkin_make`.  This appears successful because the results end with

```
[100%] Built target parser
```

But should I be seeing a new file somewhere called "parser"?  I don't see anything except the original parser.cpp file.  Now I can't understand the very last tutorial instruction.  It says:

```
  $ .<path>/parser <path>my_robot.urdf
  # ./devel/lib/robot_description/parser /src/robot_description/urdf/my_robot.urdf (for example)
```

I've tried navigating to `~/catkin_ws/src/testbot_description` and entering:

```
./src/parser /urdf/my_robot.urdf
```

But this returns:

```
bash: ./src/parser: No such file or directory
```

The following question appears to ask the same question, but the answer to the last step is not included: http://answers.ros.org/question/148686/tutorial-parse-a-urdf-file/

That suggests I should be calling `rosrun <PKG> <NAME>` *instead* of the approach used in the tutorial.  I think that means I should be calling `rosrun parser my_robot.urdf` or maybe `rosrun parser /urdf/my_robot.urdf` but running either of those still gives me:

```
[rospack] Error: package 'parser' not found
```

I think maybe I just don't have the syntax correct for this last step, but I can't figure it out from looking at the tutorial, that other question, or the rosrun documentation.  Any pointers?  Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198056/error:-package-%27parser%27-not-found/) by [SeaTail](https://answers.ros.org/users/20821/seatail/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2014-11-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Catkin follows the out-of-source build paradigm. So the binaries aren't located in your source folder. In your case they are located in `~/catkin_ws/devel/lib/<package>`.

This line you posted `# ./devel/lib/robot_description/parser /src/robot_description/urdf/my_robot.urdf (for example)` is correct, but you have to be in your catkin root directory.

The seconds approach you posted is also correct. But `<PKG>` is your package `testbot_description` and `<NAME>` the name of your node `parser`. Then append the arguments for your node `<path to your urdf>`. The correct command then looks like `rosrun testbot_description parser <path to your urdf>`

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2014-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0